# Acessar a câmera do celular em uma WebView no Android Studio

Tags: android, script, webview

Estou criando um leitor de QR code em um site e agora preciso usar este site em uma versão Mobile, para isso estou criando um WebView que está abrindo o site.

Em qualquer navegador o leitor de QR Code funciona, no desktop ou no celular. Porem quando vou usar a webview ele não da permissão para uso da câmera do Android.

Já inseri todas as permissões e verificações que encontrei na internet porem nada funciona em nenhuma versão do Android (estou utilizando a 6.0)

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera" />
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera.autofocus" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

Vi uma opção de inserir um JavaScript para chamar a câmera no WebView porem não encontrei como pode ser feito.

Caso seja necessário encaminho o código do APP.

Comment: Você usa cordova?

Answer (score 1):

Tenta atribuir as permissões na class também, e carregar seu HTML com LoadURL:

```
WebView wView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.seuWebView);

    wView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    wView.getSettings().setAllowFileAccessFromFileURLs(true);
    wView.getSettings().setAllowUniversalAccessFromFileURLs(true);

    wView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());
    wView.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient() {
        // Grant permissions for cam
        @Override
        public void onPermissionRequest(final PermissionRequest request) {
            Log.d("Log1", "onPermissionRequest");
            runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                @TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.M)
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    Log.d("Log2", request.getOrigin().toString());
                    if(request.getOrigin().toString().equals("file:///")) {
                        Log.d("Log3", "GRANTED");
                        request.grant(request.getResources());
                    } else {
                        Log.d("Log4", "DENIED");
                        request.deny();
                    }
                }
            });
        }


    });

    wView.loadUrl(SEU_HTML);
```

E quanto ao JS, use getMédia pra setar o vídeo à uma tag do seu HTML,  neste caso você cria uma tag  `<video>` no seu HTML e faz o seguinte:

```
var constraints = { video: { width: 800, height: 800 } };

    navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia(constraints)
            .then(function(mediaStream) {
        var video = document.querySelector('video');
        video.srcObject = mediaStream;
        video.onloadedmetadata = function(e) {
            video.play();
        };
    }).catch(function(err) { console.log(err.name + ": " + err.message); });
```

Tenta essas duas coisas aí, e coloca mais essa permissão no manifest, só pra garantir mesmo:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
```

Valeu mano, é noiz :D.